# How to make (where to find) scripts for GitLab CI to run GitLab pages?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy a static page using GitLab repos with plain HTML/CSS (actually SCSS). As far as I learnt, a static page needs at least `.gitlab-ci.yml` and `/public` folder. The file `.gitlab-ci.yml` will have a minimum requirement like this: ([an example from official doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#pages))

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r * .public
    - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

And my question is lying in the `script` line.
(I assume the script below will create a hidden folder name .public and copy all the file in it then move it from .public to public folder. Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

```
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r * .public
    - mv .public public
```

To me, it's similar to shell-script of Linux. It's also confirmed in [GitLab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script) that it's run by the Runner. But the problem is, how do I know how many shell-scripts are installed in GitLab? And is it possible to make one?

I would like to make 2 folders: `src` and `public`. The GitLab CI will run the script and compile SCSS from `src` then move it to `public`.

I'm using **gitlab.com** by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a few things to consider. Each job in gitlab is run in a container. Generally you specify which one you want to use. Pages is a special case though so you don't have to care about the image for the container.

The `pages` job will populate your public folder. But you can alter the `gitlab-ci.yml` file and add steps.

This would build an app using node:

```
build_stuff:
 stage: build
 image: node:11
 before_script:
 - npm install
 script:
 - npm run build
artifacts:
  paths:
 - build

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r build/ .public
    - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

**Formatting is off**

Things to note. The first step is running the build steps to generate all the assets for your output folder. It is then storing anything declared in the artifacts block, in this case the build folder, and passing it on to the next job. Adjust this step accordingly to what you need to build your app.

The only thing I altered in the second step is that you copy the contents of the build folder instead of the entire repo into the .public folder. Adjust this to your needs as well.

As for shell scripts, there are none present except for the ones you bring to the repository. The default runner supports Bash so you can execute bash commands just as you would in your terminal.

If you create the file `foo.sh` in your repo and do `bash foo.sh` it will execute the script, if it's executable. Remember to chmod it before pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "shell-scripts installed in Gitlab". Gitlab supports several [shells](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/) and the script part in your example are just pure bash commands. Since you are most probably using the default docker runner you can execute bash commands from the script part, run scripts in other languages that are in your repo, install packages on the docker container and even prepare and run your own docker images.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about 'run scripts in other languages that are in your repo'? Do you mean that if I add .sh files to my repo then I can call it from .gitlab-ci.yml? (If so, how do I do that?)

Comment: @StarLight Well, start your experiment with adding `ls` as the first line of the script, it should show you all the files that are available, that is all the files downloaded from your repo. Now you just run them like you normally would e.g. `bash test.sh` or maybe `chmod +x` them first and run directly.